# jQuery Datatables Responsive createdCell issue

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am currently working on a datatable which finally seems to work exactly the way I want, however one issue remains, please see my screenshots below:

[image]

As you can see, I am adding custom colors in the column STATUS based on the actual status value using the following code:

```
            'columnDefs': [ {
                'targets': 3,
                'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    if ( cellData == 'Pending' ) {
                        $(td).css('color', '#e27522'),
                        $(td).css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    }
                    else if ( cellData == 'Confirmed' ) {
                        $(td).css('color', 'green'),
                        $(td).css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    }
                    else if ( cellData == 'Accepted' ) {
                        $(td).css('color', 'lightgreen'),
                        $(td).css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    }}
                },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 5 }]
```

This works great, however these properties are getting removed on responsive mode.

Responsive mode:

[image]

How can I maintain these color values for status? Here my full Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#jquery-datatable-ajax-php').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'responsive': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'order': [[5, 'desc']],
            'ajax': {
            'url':'datatable.php'
            },
            'columns': [
                { data: 'client_name' },
                { data: 'quote_number' },
                { data: 'project' },
                { data: 'status' },
                { data: 'quote_total', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2,), className: 'dt-body-right'},
                { data: 'id', 'name': 'id', fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<a class='link' href='/quotes/view/"+oData.id+"?nocache=<?php echo time()?>'>View</a>");}}
            ],
            'columnDefs': [ {
                'targets': 3,
                'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    if ( cellData == 'Pending' ) {
                        $(td).css('color', '#e27522'),
                        $(td).css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    }
                    else if ( cellData == 'Confirmed' ) {
                        $(td).css('color', 'green'),
                        $(td).css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    }
                    else if ( cellData == 'Accepted' ) {
                        $(td).css('color', 'lightgreen'),
                        $(td).css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    }}
                },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 5 }]
       });
    } );
</script>
```

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the status labels for "Pending", "Confirmed" and "Accepted" inside a `<span>` element - and add a class to that element to control its formatting.

When the table is collapsed in responsive mode, the entire span will be transferred to the child record - and the formatting will be preserved.

First add some CSS styles. For simplicity, I have named the CSS classes in my styles to match the status labels. This helps me to avoid writing an `if... else...` statement for the different class names. But you can call your classes whatever you want:

```css
.Pending {
  color: #e27522;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Confirmed {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Accepted {
  color: lightgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now I can use a column renderer to build the `<span>` HTML as a text string:

```js
columnDefs: [
  { 
    targets: 5, 
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      if (type === 'display') {
        return '<span class="' + data + '">' + data + '</span>';
      } else { 
        return data;
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

**Runnable demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { 
        targets: 5, 
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (type === 'display') {
              return '<span class="' + data + '">' + data + '</span>';
          } else {
              return data;
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  } );


} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- responsive plug-in -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.dataTables.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<style>

.Pending {
  color: #e27522;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Confirmed {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Accepted {
  color: lightgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>Confirmed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>Accepted</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Additional Note**

The `type === 'display'` logic is how DataTables allows you to create a display value which is different from sorting and filtering values. If you don't do this, you will find that the word "span" (for example) will always find all rows - because of how we built the display data. But if the data type is not `display` then we just use the underlying data value (without the `<span>` text). You can read more about this "orthogonal data" [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).